# Big Json parsing in cypress, jsonPath usage

Tags: javascript, json, cypress

I'm new to cypress and I face a problem when trying to work with json responses. I am getting json with units structure(tree structure) and I need to get all the names from it.

I tried to use jsonpath dependenc and parse json using jp.query, but it doesn't works:

```
 cy.request(*some request*).its('body').then((body) => {
                let units = jp.query(body, "$..[?(@.type=='PROJECT')].name");
           })
```

I'm getting **obj needs to be an object** Assertion error here

How to fix this or maybe there are any other ways to parse json in cypress?

JSON Sample:

```
[
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Solar",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Earth",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "Moon",
                    "type": "STREAM",
                    "active": true
                }
            ],
            "type": "PROJECT",
            "active": true
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Jupiter",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "Io",
                    "type": "STREAM",
                    "active": true
                },
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "name": "Ganymede",
                    "type": "STREAM",
                    "active": true
                }
            ]},
    ],
    "type": "PROGRAM",
    "active": true
},
{
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Centaurus",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "Alpha Centauri A",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 818,
                    "name": "Alpha Centauri Aa-2345",
                    "type": "STREAM",
                    "active": true
                }
            ],
            "type": "PROJECT",
            "active": true
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "Alpha Centauri B",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "name": "Alpha Centauri Bb",
                    "type": "STREAM",
                    "active": true
                }
            ],
            "type": "PROJECT",
            "active": true
        },
    ],
    "type": "PROGRAM",
    "active": true
}
```

]

Comment: Can you check the JSON you provided? I found it to be invalid (missing a closing `}]`.) Once fixing that, I was able to successfully use the provided `jp.query` to print out the names -- `[ 'Earth', 'Alpha Centauri A', 'Alpha Centauri B' ]`.

Comment: Sorry, original json was much bigger, so that was my copypaste mistake. Fixed it now. But I still have the same issue when working with cy.request response

Comment: If you just logged the `body` in the `then` statement, does it have a value?

Comment: Yes, that's what I get in the console
`Applied to:  
{id: 1, name: 'Milky Way', children: Array(2), type: 'ORGANIZATION', active: true}
active: true
children: (2) [{…}, {…}]
id: 1
name: "Milky Way"
type: "ORGANIZATION"
[[Prototype]]: Object

cypress_runner.js:178427 Error:       AssertionError: obj needs to be an object`

Answer (score 0):

add below 2 lines before `jp.query()`

```js
body = JSON.stringify(body);
body = JSON.parse(body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the request/response is configured, you may have one of the following issues

- response is a string
- `body` is a string
- there is no `body`

```js
cy.request(*some request*)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .its('body')
  .then(body => {
    let units = jp.query(body, "$..[?(@.type=='PROJECT')].name");
  })
```

or

```js
cy.request(*some request*)
  .its('body')
  .then(body => body.json())
  .then(body => {
    let units = jp.query(body, "$..[?(@.type=='PROJECT')].name");
  })
```

or

```js
cy.request(*some request*)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(jsonObj => {
    let units = jp.query(jsonObj, "$..[?(@.type=='PROJECT')].name");
  })
```